# How to curry a method on an object for passing it as a C-style callback?

Tags: c++, object, callback, currying

Let's assume we have the following class `A`:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void sum(int x);
};
```

And we have a function `f`, which gets a C-style callback with one parameter of type `int` and calls it:

```
typedef void (*Callback)(int);

void f(Callback cb)
{
    cb(5);
}
```

Is there any way in C++ to curry a method `A::print` on an object of type `A` and pass it to the function `f`? Something like this:

```
void main()
{
    A a;
    auto curry_a = ??; // something like curry_a = [&](int x) { a.sum(x) };
    f(curry_a);
}
```

`std::bind` and lambda-function are not a solution, because they create objects of type `std::function<>` with overloaded `operator()`. It looks like currying in C++, but it cannot be used in my case. I need a real function pointer, i.e. generate code in real time.

Comment: What means of curry?

Comment: @InQusitive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Just to clarify, [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) do *not* create [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects. The objects returned by `std::bind` and lambdas can be *stored* in a `std::function` object.

Comment: I think you're confusing currying with [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, okey, they do not create `std::function` objects, but they create objects, not functions.

Comment: @molbdnilo, what is the difference between currying and partial application in my case? As far as I know, this difference is present only for functions with 3 or more parameters. In my case I have a function with 2 parameters: `A* ptr` aka `this` pointer and `int x`.

Comment: @DmitriyZakablukov Converting a function `a x b -> c` to a function `a -> b -> c` is currying. A curried function has the same number of parameters as the "original". Applying a function `a x b -> c` (or `a -> b -> c`) to an argument `a` so you get a function `b -> c` is partial application. A partially applied function has fewer parameters than the "original". A curried `sum` would be `[](A& b) { return[](int x) { return b.sum(x);};}`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, thanks for explanation! I think I got it. But the usage of curried `sum` should be `f(curried_sum(a));` and we back again to the function with 1 parameter. Or I just missing something important...

Answer (score 3):

You are out of luck, it can't be done in a satisfactory way:  The only thing that is exactly a C-compatible function pointer is a function (or class-function but not instance function).

So, you'd have to create a function that fixes a parameter, like the `this` of a member function.  The only way to set this parameter is through a global variable:

```
A *instance;
void (A::*a_fun)(int);
void applicator(int arg) { instance->*a_fun(arg); }
//...
int main() {
  A a;
  instance = &a;
  a_fun = &A::sum;
  f(applicator);
  // ...
```

That is the only way to provide context to a plain function, through global variables.

Comment: Mind you, class-variables are also global variables

Comment: Well, this is not a thread-safe solution at all. But thanks anyway. Another problem is that the function `f` is called always with the same argument `applicator` and I really want to pass **different** function pointers.

Comment: @DmitriyZakablukov like I said it leaves a lot to be desired, any solution to your question will involve "passing" the context (what function to call and the fixed arguments) as global variables. 
Also, you can pass *different* function pointers the same way you can "pass" different instances: set a global variable, in this case, the `a_fun` pointer to something else, or make another applicator wrapper for non-instance functions, and so on.